# setState dont work inside ontap async on a futureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello and thanks for reading this, i was trying to call a `setState` inside a `onTap()` function that is inside a `FutureBuilder` i was reading other threads with similar problems, but i can't find a fix, there say that problem is the `setState` dont works fine with async.

i call `setState` cause i have a `ExpansionTile` with `ListTiles` with remote data, see the code, i try to update the data gattering when i tap another option, but when i call `setState` the data gattering is maded but nothing happens in UI.

I tried to put the setState call in the `whenComplete` of the async onTap, but still no working, i readed that if i put a symbolic return and after the `setState` but still no working, i tried to put in different points of the async, i tried to delete the `showSnackBar` and see if it works with only the new data gattering function and setState, but dont works.

i hope you can uderstand me, here is a little piece of my code, if you need more, let me know:

```
                           ExpansionTile(
                              collapsedTextColor: Colors.black87,
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              collapsedBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                              title: Text(element['result'] == ''
                                  ? AppLocalizations.of(context)!.noTileSelected
                                  : element['result']),
                              children: List<Widget>.generate(
                                  6,
                                  (index) => index == 0
                                      ? ListTile(
                                          onTap: () async {
                                            bool res = await analisisModel
                                                .updateField(
                                              '',
                                              element['id'].toString(),
                                              bach,
                                              id,
                                            )
                                                .whenComplete(() {
                                              return;
                                            });

                                            if (res) {
                                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                                  .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                                content: Text(
                                                    AppLocalizations.of(
                                                            context)!
                                                        .savedSnack),
                                                duration:
                                                    Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                              ));
                                            } else {
                                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                                  .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                                content: Text(
                                                    AppLocalizations.of(
                                                            context)!
                                                        .errorSnack),
                                                duration: Duration(
                                                    milliseconds: 1500),
                                              ));
                                            }
                                            setState(() {
                                              this._future =
                                                  analisisModel.getFinalData(
                                                      idCue, bach, id);
                                            });
                                          },
                                          title: Text(
                                            '---',
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      : ListTile(
                                          title: Text(
                                              element['opci$index'] == ''
                                                  ? AppLocalizations.of(
                                                          context)!
                                                      .noRegistersText
                                                  : element['opci$index'],
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white)),
                                          onTap: () async {
                                            bool res = await analisisModel
                                                .updateField(
                                              element['opci$index'],
                                              element['id'].toString(),
                                              bach,
                                              id,
                                            )
                                                .whenComplete(() {
                                              return;
                                            });

                                            if (res) {
                                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                                  .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                                content: Text(
                                                    AppLocalizations.of(
                                                            context)!
                                                        .savedSnack),
                                                duration:
                                                    Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                              ));
                                            } else {
                                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                                  .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                                content: Text(
                                                    AppLocalizations.of(
                                                            context)!
                                                        .errorSnack),
                                                duration: Duration(
                                                    milliseconds: 1500),
                                              ));
                                            }
                                            setState(() {
                                              this._future =
                                                  analisisModel.getFinalData(
                                                      idCue, bach, id);
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ))))
```

this is the piece of code that doesn't work, i've deleted `showSnacBar` for easier reading:

```
ListTile(
   onTap: () async {
      bool res = await analisisModel.updateField(
                    '',
                    element['id'].toString(),
                    bach,
                    id,
                 ).whenComplete(() { return;});
      //that set state don't make anything in UI
      setState(() {
           this._future = analisisModel.getFinalData(
                             idCue, bach, id);
      });
    },
    title: Text('---',
                style:  TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
)
```

Comment: can you share simple code of your issue?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh offcourse, i allready added it to the post

Comment: if we add `postFrameCallback` it will change the UI state, for this case i think `ChangeNotfier` is the solution

Answer (score 1):

while using `FutureBuilder` we promised to wait only once. and it will `rebuild` only once, if you are trying to modify value like using `setState` inside `FutureBuilder` or even outside of that widget, it will rebuild everything. better you can use `stateManagement`  for this situation.

here is an example how `FutureBuilder` rebuild everytime.

```
class CalculatableTextFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CalculatableTextFormFieldState createState() =>
      _CalculatableTextFormFieldState();
}

class _CalculatableTextFormFieldState extends State<CalculatableTextFormField> {
  int data = 0;
  int _numberOfFuture = 0;

  Future<int> dummyFuture() async {
    print("future called ${_numberOfFuture++}");
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) => 4);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Text("inside FutureBuilder"),
        FutureBuilder<int>(
          future: dummyFuture(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData &&
                snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Builder(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return Text(
                        "Got Data from Future $data",
                        key: ValueKey("text"),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      bool result = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2))
                          .then((value) => true);
                      if (result)
                        setState(() {
                          data++;
                        });

                      print("after click $data");
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Click",
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            } else
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Text("just setState")),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it "works" (i changes the UI), but when i tap the `ListTile`, another `ExpansionTile` magically appears ex. if i have 2 expansionTiles in my screen when i tap, i have 4 expansionTiles, all with the same data of the first 2.